# Excel: Output based on selection from multiple drop down menus

Tags: excel

I want to output one of the number of options in Excel based on the selection of several drop down menus.

For example, chose a specific shirt design from a number of options based on the Age, Gender, and Size of a person, where those three variable can be selected from three drop down menus, assuming I have a matrix to figure out the appropriate options as below:

[image: Options Matrix]

Are there any functions in Excel I might use to achieve this? Or will I have to use Visual Basic?

Thanks!

Comment: When the person picks from the age drop down, are there 15 options (from 0 to 14) or are there only 3 options (0-4, 5-9, and 10-14)? If they are specifying an age group, you can use your matrix as is and do a complex lookup, but if they're specifying an exact age you need to modify your matrix to add a couple rows to the top of that list specifying the minimum and maximum ages that fall into each age group before you can do a complex look up, so that you don't need to add the complexity of parsing strings to your lookup formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for VBA here, all you need is some helper logic and and INDEX/MATCH formula:

1. The options need to be unique and only have one element per option group per line. In your example it means you need to split Options 5, 6 and 9 as they each have multiple age groups - see the yellow lines:
   [image]
2. You need to encode your options in some way, e.g. 0-4=4, 5-9=9, 10-14=14, Male = M, etc.. Then you can translate each of the options into one unique 3 letter text, e.g. option 1 would be `4ML`. In the below example, the following formula was used to construct the ID in cell J3:

   ```
   =INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH("x",B3:D3))&INDEX($E$1:$F$1,MATCH("x",E3:F3))&INDEX($G$1:$I$1,MATCH("x",G3:I3))
   ```

   [image]
3. You also need to translate the selection from the drop downs into the code. The formula for the yellow cell is:

   ```
   =INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(M1,$B$2:$D$2,0))
   &INDEX($E$1:$F$1,MATCH(M2,$E$2:$F$2,0))
   &INDEX($G$1:$I$1,MATCH(M3,$G$2:$I$2,0))
   ```

   [image]
4. Now you only need to translate the code into the option using the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$16,MATCH(M4,$J$3:$J$16,0)),"No option for this selection!")
```

Note that this will show a small text in case the selected option is not available.

For better understanding, you can find the [example file here](https://mega.co.nz/#!Wcw2nIwS!Ft6NC0btf_-u9Wk1jsKq22A7tls-FQs-xOuM0olNiso).